# Does the Software Centre provide a DRM/licensing scheme?

Tags: software-center

Does Ubuntu's Software Centre include a DRM/licensing mechanism so that applications can only be installed and run by the people who purchase them?

I'm thinking of something similar to Apple's where only a user with a particular AppleID can use software they purchase through the App Store.

If there is nothing built in, are there any solutions available to developers to implement something similar in their applications?

Answer (score 10):

The Ubuntu Store does not implement DRM/licensing as a policy; that goes against the ethos of [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) (upon which Linux/Ubuntu are founded).

Commercial apps may choose to implement some type of DRM/licensing, that is up to the individual authors. Otherwise, most such authors rely on the **honor system** -- that a user will only use the app if you have paid for it.

From [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/):

> There is no native DRM framework within Ubuntu so there is no
>   system-wide restrictions. We do not believe that DRM is a successful
>   formula because  it punishes law-abiding users and doesn’t stop the
>   minority of pirates.  However, we do not limit individual developers
>   from using their own rights management system.